# Are there any books where Aristotlean quotations are collected?

Tags: reference-request, aristotle

Are there any books where Aristotle's quotations are available?

Comment: There are many modern editions of [A's works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Works_by_Aristotle); see e.g. [Oxford edition](https://books.google.it/books?id=FP5sAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome, jasmine

I don't know of any collection of quotations from Aristotle, which doesn't mean there isn't such a collection. There are lexicons in which key Aristotelian terms and concepts are listed and explained: for example,

https://files.meetup.com/1715539/A%20Basic%20Aristotle%20Glossary.pdf

*I don't think a collection of quotations is what you need, however. One doesn't get to know a philosopher through quotations, which usually have no or little context*. It's much better to do either or both of two thngs:

1. Start to read an Aristotelian text. In my teaching career I have had to read all Aristotle's major works but the first book I read was his *Rhetoric*, which is relatively easy to get into. From there you could work out into other texts such as his *Politics* and *Nicomachean Ethics*.
2. You could read one of the many excellent introductions to Aristotle. I'd recommend:

Jonathan Barnes' *Aristotle: A Very Short Introduction*, ISBN 10: 0192854089 / ISBN 13: 9780192854087, published by Oxford University Press, United Kingdom, 2001

or

R. McKeon, ed., Introduction to Aristotle, ISBN 10: 0075536528 / ISBN 13: 9780075536529, published by McGraw-Hill Education.

It's very likely that in tackling the *Nicomachean Ethics* some such introduction is useful or even essential. This is not a particularly technical text but on the surface it's a flat read and there are points  - interesting and important points - you'll probably miss without a guide to draw them out.

The world of Aristotle is rich, fascinating and complex. Do step into it - but I suggest you leave quotations behind.